# Codeigniter update form does not submit

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, forms, codeigniter

Codeigniter offers you a tutorial to get to know it and how to use it. This tutorial teaches you to create elements in a table in a database, but doesn't teach you how to update this elements. I am trying to make an update query using the codeigniter libraries, but the form from de update view doesn't submit.

AT NEWS_MODEL:

```js
public function update_news($slug)
   {

   $this->load->helper('url');

   $data = array(
                  'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
                  'slug' => $slug,
                  'text' => $this->input->post('text')
               );

   $this->db->where('slug', $slug);
   $this->db->update('news', $data); 

   }
```

AT NEWS CONTROLLER:

```js
public function update($slug)
        {

            $this->load->helper('form');
            $this->load->library('form_validation');

            $data['title'] = 'Update a news item';

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('text', 'Text', 'required');


            if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
            {
              // The form was NOT posted
              // So we load the view
              $data['news_item'] = $this->news_model->get_news($slug);
              $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
              $this->load->view('news/update', $data);
              $this->load->view('templates/footer');

            }
            else
            {
              // The form was submitted
              $data = array(
           'title' => $this->input->post('title'), //-->post variable
           'slug'  => $this->input->post('slug'),
           'text' => $this->input->post('text')
                );

              $this->news_model->update_news($slug, $data);
              $this->load->view('news/success');
            }
          }
```

AT UPDATE VIEW:

```js
<h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<?php  echo form_open('news/update') ;?>

<label for="title">Title</label>
<input type="input" name="title" /><br />

<label for="text">Text</label>
<textarea name="text"></textarea><br />

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update news item" />

</form>
```

I've tested the code with "console.log()" and the problem seems to be that the form of the update view doesn't submit, but I cannot figure why, because the form is similar to the create form, which does work perfectly:

```js
<h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<?php echo form_open('news/create'); ?>

    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="input" name="title" /><br />

    <label for="text">Text</label>
    <textarea name="text"></textarea><br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create news item" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is :
you use `===` instead of `==` in this line:

```
 if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
```

Comment: It was that way at the Codeigniter example code, anyway I've just tried to change it and it still doesn't work.

Comment: The error is a "not found 404" but I'm sure that is because of the form in the update view, I just don't know how to solve it.

Comment: I think the problem come from your config.php file,are u sure that,u set `$config['base_url']`??

Comment: $config['base_url'] is set. It comes already set in the config.php of Codeigniter (I've just checked)

Comment: In `form_open('news/create');` command you call create function,this function get one paramter `[$slug]` but in `form_open('news/create');` you did not send any,first fix this up

Comment: Thank you! That helped me a lot! I finally managed to make it work.

Comment: What was your problem?

Comment: At <?php  echo form_open('news/update') ;?> I had to use <?php  echo form_open('news/update/'.$slug) ;?> (send parameter, as you said). And I got $slug from the url like this: <?php $urlarray=explode("/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); $slug=$urlarray[sizeof($urlarray)-1]; echo $slug;?>